# Cross-compilation with OpenCV

Tags: cross-compilation, opencv

I'm stuck in cross-compilation my RPi with OpenCV, my project just one file main.cpp and build success in my computer by this [tut](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html). I want to run it in RPi. I read this [tut](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/crosscompilation/arm_crosscompile_with_cmake.html) but can't understand much, and have some questions:

```
- Is this tut true for all ARM architecture include RPi?
- Why we have to make folder build_hardfp?
- In this line : cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../arm-gnueabi.toolchain.cmake ../../..
    I dont understand "../arm-gnueabi.toolchain.cmake ../../.. " could you explain them?
```

Comment: Before you get stuck in the cross-compiling mindset, is there some reason you can't compile on the Pi directly?

Comment: Because it took so much time.

Comment: It may still be faster than trying to cross-compile.